# Rails 5 Column Named Root Misbehaving

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, postman

I am attempting to create a restful API in Rails 5, one of my classes has an attribute named root. This root attribute has caused a few errors, I will provide one example. Is root a protected attribute name in rails or ruby?

```
class ObjectsController < ApplicationController
  before_action only: %i[create]

  def create
    @object = Object.create(object_params)
    render json: @object
  end

  private


  def object_params
    params.require(:object).permit(:id, :root)
  end
```

When I post to /objects/
with something like the following:

```
{"object": {"id": "manual_id" , "root": "manual_root"}}
```

I am returned with the following in Postman:

```
{
    "id": "manual_id",
    "root": null,
    "extension": "manual_extension"
}
```

But in the MySQL database the value for root is manual_root.
Has anyone any ideas of what the issue may be.

Comment: Can't find anywhere that root is a reserved word in rails but there is a namespace in routes called `root` so I would suggest not using this word.

Comment: Read here: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#using-root.

Comment: Please do this: 1. `puts "*"*100 puts params puts "*"*100` in 3 separate lines before and after line 5 in your ObjectsController and examine the params between the asterisks in your server console. Something fishy is happening to your params.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @ARK I've found the solution and will add the answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add an attribute alias to the model like so:

```
class Object < ApplicationRecord
  alias_attribute :object_root, :root
end
```

and use this attribute in the object serializer class:

```
class ObjectSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :object_root
end
```

So my problem was with the active model serializer, I believe that root is a reserved keyword. Here is a similar issue: https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/issues/1135